# How do I save files on Macbook with crashed OS?

Tags: macbook-pro, data-transfer, unibody, target-disk-mode

I have a Macbook that the OS has crashed (I am not 100% sure if the Hard Drive is dead, but I would like to save the files before anything else).

When I boot up, the screen just remains grey and there is a spinner that stays on forever.

I thought that if I got a thunderbolt cable and connected that Macbook to my other Macbook Pro, I could boot the crashed drive Macbook into Target mode and then get access to the files.

That doesn't seem to be working and now I am re-reading the instructions it seems that the target computer needs to be bootable (i.e. into OS X, which mine is not). I'm not familiar with how to take this unibody MacBook Pro apart.

So how do I get access to those files, before I reinstall the OS?

Comment: Do both laptops support thunderbolt?  Sounds like the aluminum MacBook is display port only.

Comment: What model MacBook Pro do you have? Target mode turns your Mac into a glorified hard drive, so if it's not mounting then you have hardware problems or the drive is toast and needs professional recovery. Also, it's simple to pull out HDD from MacBook Pro so I'm not sure why you added that. Perhaps you have an SSD that's not portable inside?

Comment: I thought thunderbolt was backwards compatible with the display port...or am I mistaken?

Comment: @bmike Not sure the exact model, but I bought it in 2008/09 I believe - it is a full body unibody aluminium MBP. Do you have a link with instructions on how to remove the HDD?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5219   List of compatible models for thunderbolt

Comment: @marcamillion ifixit.com has take apart instructions and apple.com/support/manuals has manuals for that era computer. It will explain how to boot to target mode as well as [identify your MacBook Pro](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201300).

Comment: @bmike I tried the instructions re: booting to target mode - and that's what threw me for a loop (i.e. it seems that the default instructions require you to have a working OS - which is my problem, because my OS has crashed).

Comment: If your Mac is too old to support Internet Recovery (where Apple runs a netboot server on the internet for you), then you are correct and you will need bootable media or another Mac to bootstrap the process. Without knowing the exact model, it's a guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to used your other Macbook Pro to create a Linux boot CD or USB drive, then boot your Macbook from that. By default Ubuntu has read access to HFS+ formatted drives so that should allow you to read your files. Assuming the drive responds.

Some resources:

- [How to burn a DVD on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)
- [How do I boot the live CD on a Macbook Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/q/71189/17022)

Comment: Any ideas on this question? - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162570/how-do-i-change-permissions-of-folders-on-a-hard-drive-from-a-booted-usb-drive